# Update a property in singleton (python)

Tags: python, singleton

EDIT: Added Ralf's recommendation to use os.environ

Trying to implement a singleton logger so that everytime a logger instance is generated, it'll only write to a specific filename.  Until a new filename is specified.

```
import logging

def singleton(myClass):                                             
    instances = {}                                                  
    def getInstance(*args,**kwargs):
        if myClass not in instances:
           instances[myClass] = myClass(*args,**kwargs)         
        return instances[myClass]                                   
    return getInstance                                              

@singleton
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.filename = os.environ['logger_filename']
        self.log = self.init_logger()

    def init_logger(self):
        fh = logging.FileHandler(self.filename + '.log')
        fmt = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)-6s: %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s)")
        fh.setFormatter(fmt)
        local_logger = logging.getLogger(self.filename)
        local_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        local_logger.addHandler(fh)

        return local_logger
```

What i have above will always write in "test1.log" file.

```
os.environ['logger_filename'] = "test1"

a = Logger()
b = Logger()

a.log.debug("Hello A")
b.log.debug("Hello B")

os.environ['logger_filename'] = "test2"

c = Logger()
c.log.debug("Hello C")
```

Since the singleton will contain the Logger class in the instances, thus it will just return that instance and not run the `__init__`

If I update the singleton with the following:

```
def singleton(myClass):
    instances = {}
    def getInstance(*args,**kwargs):
        if myClass not in instances:
           instances[myClass] = myClass(*args,**kwargs)
        else:
            instances[myClass].update_logger()
        return instances[myClass]
    return getInstance

@singleton
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.filename = os.environ['logger_filename']
        self.log = self.init_logger()

    def init_logger(self):
        fh = logging.FileHandler(self.filename + '.log')
        fmt = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)-6s: %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s)")
        fh.setFormatter(fmt)
        local_logger = logging.getLogger(self.filename)
        local_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        local_logger.addHandler(fh)

        return local_logger

    def update_logger(self):
        self.filename = os.environ['logger_filename']
        self.log = self.init_logger()


os.environ['logger_filename'] = "test1"


a = Logger()
b = Logger()

a.log.debug("Hello A")
b.log.debug("Hello B")

os.environ['logger_filename'] = "test2"

c = Logger()
c.log.debug("Hello C")
```

This will now generate 2 log files (test1 and test2).  But test1 will contain two "Hello A" and two "Hello B".  How do i get to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You give very few specific details, so I'll give an answer that should work, but I don't know if that is what you wanted.

How about you store the current filename in a environment variable using [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html#os.environ)?

You can modify the `singleton` function:

```
import os

def singleton(myClass):                                             
    ...
        if myClass not in instances:
           kwargs['filename'] = os.environ['logger_filename']  # may raise KeyError
           instances[myClass] = myClass(*args, **kwargs)         
    ...

@singleton
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
    ...
```

Or another option is to just modify the logger class:

```
import os

@singleton
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.filename = os.environ['logger_filename']  # may raise KeyError
```

---

With any of these two options you just have to modify the value of the environment variable to set a different target for your loggers:

```
import os
os.environ['logger_filename'] = 'f1.log'

b = Logger() 
b.log.debug("hello there")    # writes on 'f1.log'

os.environ['logger_filename'] = 'f2222.log'

c = Logger() 
c.log.debug("hello there")    # writes on 'f2222.log'
```

Comment: I guess that works.  Was thinking of using some kind of global variable, didnt think of this.  This definitely would be the better way to go.  Thanks

Comment: Actually this doesnt work.  Since the singleton will just return the instance with the old filename, thus 'c' will still write on f1.log since the __init__ wont run from the Logger and the singleton will just return the instance

Comment: Hm... a workaround would be to clear the dict, like `Logger.instances.clear()` after changing the environment variable

Comment: I updated the question so that you can see what I tried.  How do I access and clear instances from singleton function? I cant seem to get that attribute

Comment: Try calling `local_logger.handlers.clear()` before `local_logger.addHandler(fh)`

Comment: And you should add the file extension `.log` to the class attribute for consistency, `self.filename = os.environ['logger_filename'] + '.log'`